# CSS3 transform: translate maximum value?

Tags: css, google-chrome, infinite-scroll, bigdata

I created an experiment to [infinite-scroll the first billion digits of Pi](https://daniellamb.com/experiments/infinite-pi/) to find/create a scrolling solution that has high-performance with a massive dataset. I started testing with [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com) and ran into an issue.

[image: infinite-scroll the first billion digits of Pi]

This demo works great (in Chrome) till around 33 million `transform: translate(0px, 3.35545e+07px);`

You can see the issue by running the following commands in the dev tools console, then scrolling.

```
scroller.scrollTo(0, -33553700); scroller._execEvent('scroll');
```

Any CSS experts know the limits of `transform: translate`?

**Update**: FYI, I see the same issue at ~33 million when using `position: absolute`.

Comment: Seems oddly close to the 25-bit value of 33554432

Answer (score 0):

For firefox, the maximum scale() multiplier is equal to the maximum browser CSS height/width / element height/width. If your calculated element's height/width exceeds this limit, then your element won't be scaled anymore.

Some people say , In chrome the maximum scale() multiplier/divider seems to be 10000

Comment: Interesting, but just so be clear, I'm not looking to scale any content just translate the position of the element (so I can smoothly recycle them). FYI I saw the same issue at 33 million when using `position: absolute`.

Comment: Numbers over 10,000 are represented in inline Chrome styles as exponential numbers, so if you do something like `parseInt(transform.split('(')[1])`, your translate value will "magically" wrap back to 1 (10,000 is `1e+4`). If that is the case, you should instead use `parseFloat`.