# Carousel transition end before displaying all content

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, animation

I'm currently making a carousel that scrolls logos but I have a problem.
If the number of logos is too high, the animation ends before all the logos are displayed.

Is there a way to make all the logos appear before resetting the animation?

Here's an example of my carousel (here it works well because the number of images is small, but if I add more, it's a problem).

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))
  }
}

.slide-track {
  animation: scroll 50s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
}
```

Here is a working example in Codepen.
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/studiojvla/pen/qVbQqW)

Comment: You should look into a JavaScript solution if you want your carroussel to dynamically adapt to the amount of slides.

Answer (score 0):

If your slides count is not going to change dynamically, and you are not to use javascript, I recommend you to use your slides count and also the container width in your calculations in order to make the animation work as desired:

```
$slides-count: 16;
$slide-width: 250px;
$container-width: 960px;

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc($container-width - ($slide-width * $slides-count)))
  }
}

.slide-track {
  animation: scroll 50s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: flex;
  width: calc($slides-count * $slide-width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the number of logos is too high, the animation ends before all the logos are displayed.

according to your code, you'v make sure of tow factors  :

- adding more logos needs to add it in fallback

  for example your slides in HTML structure goes like this:

  img1,img2,img3,img4,**img1,img2,img3,img4**

  so to add more logos should be added twice:

  img1,img2,img3,img4,**img5**,img1,img2,img3,img4,**img5**

---

- Since we added more logo items we have to increase Slide animation number to match how many logos displaying:

```
@keyframes scroll {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }

    100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7 ))}
}
```

demo example *[in this demo I added 17 logo items]*:

```css
body {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 17));
            transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 17));
  }
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 17));
            transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 17));
  }
}
.slider {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.slider::before, .slider::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(white), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slider .slide-track {
  -webkit-animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
          animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
}
.slider .slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <div class="slide-track">
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
    <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is SASS version :

```css
body {
 align-items: center;
 background: #E3E3E3;
 display: flex;
 height: 100vh;
 justify-content: center;
}

@mixin white-gradient {
 background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}

$animationSpeed: 10s;

// Animation
@keyframes scroll {
 0% { transform: translateX(0); }
 100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 17))}
}


// Styling
.slider {
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 960px;
 
 &::before,
 &::after {
  @include white-gradient;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
 
 &::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
 }

 &::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 
 .slide-track {
  animation: scroll $animationSpeed linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
 }
 
 .slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to do that with 49 images son i modified the transform in the keyframe but my animation still restart with a break during the animation. should I change something else ?

Comment: I did some calculation and It looks that browser limit about 10,000px and your Carousel 12,250‬px (250px * 49) . this question have a similar experience https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330152/css3-transform-translate-maximum-value. so you have to depend on JavaScript

Comment: what about I put the width at 100px * 49, it should work ?